# How to use DisplayFor to display a list of hrefs

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an MVC project that has a list of items. I use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ListOfItems)
```

when running, this shows the list of items. In the markup, it is displayed like this:

```
item1item2item3item4
```

But I want them in an `ul` so that I can make them hrefs. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple, use a `foreach` loop:

```
<ul>
@foreach(var item in Model.ListOfItems)
{
    <li><a href="@Html.DisplayFor(m => item)">Some text</a></li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: I like this answer but maybe you should edit it to include the hrefs the OP was talking about, for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see that @SteveS